# Which feature is activated for network drive mapping

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am mapping network drive from SharePoint online. Which feature should I activate?

Answer (score 5):

For mapping your Network drive with SharePoint Online you need to add SharePoint Online Site URL to the trusted site on the IE.

Open Internet Explorer :

1. Internet Option
2. In Security Tab select **Trusted sites**
3. Sites

[image]

And make Sure **WebClient** windows service is running under Local Service account.

[image]

> This is the WebDEV service running on the windows desktop making
>   SharePoint online libraries available through windows explorer or any
>   other windows client utilities. E.g. if you are planning to sync
>   OneDrive for Business to your OneDrive client and sync doesn’t work,
>   you may want to ensure this service has started.

Comment: i've been using local intranet zone and it works that way too. 'official document' is at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2507767/problems-when-signing-out-of-office-365--azure--or-intune-in-a-web-bro  They say add it to your trusted sites, then add it to your intranet. doesn't step 2 negate step one?